# I can't get the Mill

Tags: candy-box

I have read that the Mill would unlock when I got around 10,000 lollipops, but I have almost 1 million and I can't find the Button anywhere. Is there something else I need to discover? I went as far as the entrance to the castle in the quests and still couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you playing Candy Box or Candy Box 2?

If you are playing Candy Box 2, then you can build a mill by going to [the Lollipop Farm](https://candybox2.gamepedia.com/The_Lollipop_farm). Once you have 10,000 lollipops, you'll have an option there to build a mill.

If you are playing Candy Box, however, you cannot build a mill. That structure is new for the sequel and did not exist in the original game.

Comment: I have 2millions lollipops, a farm with 1.2millions lollipops planted but there is no option to build a mill. :/